# Prettyprint format not styling code correctly

Tags: jquery

I'm thinking about adding a blog to my site, so I'm using Prettyprint to style the code, problem is the styling is not displaying correctly as can be seen by the image.

[image]

line 1 is blank and the last 2 lines are blank and 2nd line is to far to the right.

I tried to write some code in jQuery but it to aggressive and removed all the indents.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".prettyprint").each(function (index, element) {
        element.textContent = element.textContent.replace(/^\s+/mg, "");
    });
});
```

As image below shows

[image]

So does anyone know how to remove the empty lines and pull 2nd line to left

**Controller Code and partial**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult DisplayCode(IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> comps)
        {
            var components = comps;

            CodeBlock subModel = null;

            foreach (var item in components)
            {

                string codeBlockText = item.GetPropertyValue<string>("codeBlock", "No Code Found");

                subModel = new CodeBlock
                {
                    TextString = codeBlockText
                };
            }

            var primaryModel = new NestedContentViewModel
            {
                DisplayCodeBlock = subModel
            };
            return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/pvCodeBlock.cshtml", primaryModel);
        }

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <pre class="prettyprint linenums:1">
                <code>
                    @Model.DisplayCodeBlock.TextString.Trim()
                </code>
                </pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need to see the code where prettyprint is inserted into the HTML; I suspect it is an artefact of some templating system, where you have whitespace between `<pre>` tag and the markup generated by prettyprint.

Comment: Hi Amadam, the input is from a textarea in CMS, I tried adding the html, but it did not format correctly on Stackoverflow

Comment: Just saying it is coming from textarea doesn't help, unfortunately. As for SO formatting - any code should either be indented four spaces (block code - you can do that automatically by selecting it and hitting Ctrl-K, or Cmd-K on Mac), or be surrounded by backticks, `` `like this` `` (especially HTML).

Comment: I've added the html

Comment: No, you misunderstand - not the final HTML code of the page. I wanted to see how this code was generated. How you use this library (the name is too generic so I have no idea what it is). What you did in order to integrate it with your blog. The source code, if you will.

Comment: Added code for how html is generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squash this:

```
<pre class="prettyprint linenums:1">
    <code>
        @Model.DisplayCodeBlock.TextString.Trim()
    </code>
</pre>
```

into this:

```
<pre class="prettyprint linenums:1"><code>@Model.DisplayCodeBlock.TextString.Trim()</code></pre>
```

`<pre>` is preserving whitespace for you (which is critical for code, because otherwise you would not be able to have indent). However, *this includes the whitespace you leave between `<pre>` and the content, and the content and `</pre>`.* For example, you were wondering why there are two blank lines after the code. It is because you have one newline between `...Trim()` and `</code>`, and then another newline between `</code>` and `</pre>`.

Tl;dr: Whenever you use `<pre>`, remember to remove any whitespace that you do not wish to see in the web page.

Comment: Was that it, I spent ages trying to work this out :( thanks